# Ticket company sent me extra tickets, can they charge me for it?

Tags: united-states, online-payment, online-shopping

I was buying some tickets from a reseller app. I accidentally clicked on return so I had to purchase a second set of tickets.
Couple days ago the tickets were sent to my Ticket Master account, including the ones I clicked on return. Which means I now have 2 orders of these tickets.
I want to sell these extra tickets online. But I was wondering if the APP finds out they sent me extra tickets, Are they able to charge me without permission if I can’t return those tickets.

Comment: What country are you in? Different countries have different consumer laws.

Comment: did you read all the fine print related to those ticket sales? Did they charge your/card account for either set of tickets?

Comment: @MikeScott I am in the United States.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I was only charged for one set of tickets. And no there are no fine prints.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they can charge you. You have the tickets.

Obviously, there is some sort of glitch that happened.  You purchased two sets of tickets and returned one, and somehow you still have both sets of tickets.  Obviously, they did not intend to send you free tickets.  So here are the possibilities of what will happen:

1. They will take back (or ask you to send back) the extra tickets.
2. They will charge you for the extra tickets.
3. They will not discover the error, and nothing will happen.

Because these tickets are electronic, it is also very possible that their system does not show the tickets being sent to you, and the system might sell them to someone else.  In that case, you do not really have two sets of tickets, and you would be selling bad tickets to whoever you sell them to.

To protect yourself from being charged, you should contact them and tell them what happened, so that they can take back the tickets and you won't have to worry about being charged for them later.